# How can I read the preferences XML file?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

How can I read the `preferences.xml` file in Android? I'd like to read and parse the XML file to collect the names of all the string resources that are used.

Comment: use PreferenceManager. Reference:http://rominirani.com/?s=android+preferences

Comment: see Resources#getXml()

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can get the value from SharedPreferences

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(sharedpre_name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY", defaultvalue);
```

Comment: That would return the value of the setting and the raw XML document itself.